# JQuery mobile flipswitch hover

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to disable the hover effect on my Flipswitch button created with JQuery mobile.
You could see on this fiddler [Flipswitch][1]
If the button is "Off" then nothing will happen when you move the mouse over the button, but if the switch is on then the white text changes to black.
Is the some easy way to disable this effect on this button only without interfere with the rest of the page.
I have tried with ThemeRoller but i cant seems to find the right attribute for that function.

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/AH6PJ/42/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the hover css:

```
.ui-flipswitch-on:hover {
    color: white !important;
    text-shadow: rgb(0, 85, 153) 0px 1px 0px !important;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AH6PJ/43/)**